# Slow accept() in socket server in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server, bind

I have the following code for my education socket server in C.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

double get_wall_time()
{
    struct timeval time;
    if (gettimeofday(&time, NULL)){
        return 0;
    }
    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * 0.000001;
}

double get_cpu_time()
{
    return (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int main()
{
    double wall = get_wall_time();
    double cpu = get_cpu_time();

    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in own_addr = {0};
    own_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    own_addr.sin_port = htons(5678);

    bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&own_addr, sizeof(own_addr));
    listen(sfd, 5);

    static char message[] = "hello from server\n";

    double wall_accept = 0;
    double cpu_accept = 0;

    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (count++ == 1000) {
            break;
        }

        double wall_start = get_wall_time();
        double cpu_start = get_cpu_time();
        int client_sfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);
        wall_accept += get_wall_time() - wall_start;
        cpu_accept += get_cpu_time() - cpu_start;

        send(client_sfd, message, sizeof(message), 0);
        close(client_sfd);
    }

    wall = get_wall_time() - wall;
    cpu = get_cpu_time() - cpu;

    printf("wall accept: %lf\n", wall_accept);
    printf("cpu accept: %lf\n", cpu_accept);

    printf("wall: %lf\n", wall);
    printf("cpu: %lf\n", cpu);
}
```

To test I use `seq 1000 | time parallel -j 1 -n0 'nc 127.0.0.1 5678' | wc -l` with results

```
wall accept: 6.436480
cpu accept: 0.010000
wall: 6.456266
cpu: 0.020000
```

For 10000 requests result is

```
wall accept: 55.434541
cpu accept: 0.080000
wall: 55.633679
cpu: 0.260000
```

Is `accept()` slow or I do something wrong? Or maybe this is normal result for single-thread implementation?

**UPD.** I also wrote a server with pthreads to send a message in different thread.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double get_wall_time()
{
    struct timeval time;
    if (gettimeofday(&time, NULL)){
        return 0;
    }
    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * 0.000001;
}

double get_cpu_time()
{
    return (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

void *send_message(void *pclient_sfd)
{
    int client_sfd = *(int *)pclient_sfd;
    free(pclient_sfd);

    static char message[] = "hello from server\n";
    send(client_sfd, message, sizeof(message), 0);
    close(client_sfd);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    double wall = get_wall_time();
    double cpu = get_cpu_time();

    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in own_addr = {0};
    own_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    own_addr.sin_port = htons(5678);

    bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&own_addr, sizeof(own_addr));
    listen(sfd, 5);

    double wall_accept = 0;
    double cpu_accept = 0;

    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (count++ == 10000) {
            break;
        }

        int *pclient_sfd = malloc(sizeof(*pclient_sfd));

        double wall_start = get_wall_time();
        double cpu_start = get_cpu_time();

        *pclient_sfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);

        wall_accept += get_wall_time() - wall_start;
        cpu_accept += get_cpu_time() - cpu_start;

        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, send_message, (void *)pclient_sfd);
    }

    wall = get_wall_time() - wall;
    cpu = get_cpu_time() - cpu;

    printf("wall accept: %lf\n", wall_accept);
    printf("cpu accept: %lf\n", cpu_accept);

    printf("wall: %lf\n", wall);
    printf("cpu: %lf\n", cpu);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I use `seq 10000 | time parallel -j 4 -n0 'nc 127.0.0.1 5678' | wc -l` and it takes 58 seconds.

Comment: Are you taking into account the fact that the accept() call will block until an incoming TCP connection is received?  (That would explain why accept() takes up a lot of wall-clock time but not much CPU-time)

Comment: Yes, I know that. Do you want to say that `parallel nc...` will have a delay between connections?

Comment: Let me guess: your computer has 8 cores? Many versions of `nc` have a bug that they call `select()` at least once with wait time of 1 second. Meaning that smallest wall clock time of those versions of `nc` is at least 1 second. Run your `nc` under `strace`. Try newer `netcat` tool instead.

Comment: @Dummy00001, maybe you are right. I wrote my own simple tcp client and get 0.003289 sec per `accept()` call on server. It's 4 seconds for 1000 requests and 34 seconds for 10000 requests. Is it normal time for `accept()`?

Comment: That is slow, but acceptable for something quickly put together. You really can't measure the performance of `accept()` in case of blocking server: you need either parallelization (either threads or forking server (call blocking accept in child processes)) or non-blocking operation.

Comment: @Dummy00001 I have a task to compare a performance of server with threads (one thread per client) and epoll/kqueue. All I want to know is it normal that 10000 requests takes 34 seconds? With pthreads (one thread per client for send a message) I have the same situation. Is it the highest performance for this realization?

Comment: @zodiac, sorry, I have never measured this performance. I generally go directly for async non-blocking mode ("epoll/kqueue" in your case). But the code above is not the same as "one thread per client", since you can call `accept()` on the same listening socket in multiple threads simultaneously. Under normal circumstances, the performance of the `accept()` is not the critical part: it's what you do with the accepted connection (e.g. in my last application, I could only accept 250 connections per second, because the client authentication was that slow).

Comment: @zodiac, this historical page might be of interest: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html . Also check: http://libevent.org/ and http://libev.schmorp.de/bench.html .

Comment: What happens if you omit the `send()` function, and simple `accept()`, then `close()`, the `client_sfd`?  _I.e._ how much latency might be being contributed by that `send()` function, since that needs to complete before you loop around to accept the next connection?

Comment: @Castaglia, without `send()` there is the same results as described in question for both realizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the way you're testing it. When you use this

```
seq 10000 | time parallel -j 4 -n0 'nc 127.0.0.1 5678' | wc -l
```

That's actually going to impact the test because you're spawning lots of processes etc ie you're not actually testing the C application your testing the ability to spawn processes.

If we change this to a simple python script ie

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5678
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
msg = "1" 

for i in range(0, 1000):
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
  data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
  s.close()
  print("received data: %s" % data)
```

and run the test the results are vastly different.

```
real    0m0.269s
user    0m0.074s
sys     0m0.114s
```

If you really want to test this and see how fast it is you need to use separate machines etc and typically you might need to use C or your limiting factor might be the client. The best tool I've seen for this (HTTP Specific) where you might find some good code is `wrk`

https://github.com/wg/wrk

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your listen() second argument. Try to increase it.
here is text from `man 2 listen`

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of
>   pending connections for sockfd may grow.  If a  connection  request 
>   arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error with
>   an indication of ECONNREFUSED or, if the underlying protocol supports
>   retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt
>   at connection succeeds.